# Session Issue while two users login in same browser at same time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a new bee in codeigniter. I have done a web based application. Login and log out works fine. But the issue is when two users  try to login in same browser, the first user is getting logout and he is getting 2nd users page and stuffs. I don't know where I did wrong. Is there any way to prevent multiple users to login in same browser?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! can you share what you have tried ?

Comment: if you will use a same pc and same browser than it will cause the problem.. try using two different pcs....

Comment: it's hardly possible sharing one session to log in two users

Comment: have you searched here first? there are several [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079630/multiple-sessions-in-codeigniter-php) like yours, or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075658/multiple-session-instances-codeigniter). So play around with the session i'ds.

Comment: Do you really have a use case for 2 users using the same browser on the same PC? if not you would just have to prevent a user logging in if there is already an open session.
If you need this solely for testing you can use 2 different browser or use chromes icognito mode for the second user.

Comment: This both user's are like one from front-end and other from back-end or so ?  In that case you should require to give different name of session name in both config file.

Answer (score 1):

That's just how it works ...

Neither your application, nor the browser (by default) can make a difference between two actual users. The same browser means the same user - it's that simple.